# Error for showing rows that equal 0 in vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am currently developing a booking system for a hotel. I have an error when I want to show if a room is available or not. When no room is booked on a certain date the data will show up so that they can book the room. But when the room is not available I want a message to say that the room is unavailable but it keeps coming with an error that stops the program.

I have tried an if statement but it hasn't been working, although I have probably done it wrong as I am a beginner.

Here is the code that calls the select statement to show the available rooms.

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles          Button1.Click

Dim SearchDB As New HotelTableAdapters.Room_TypeTableAdapter
Dim GetAvailaibility As Hotel.Room_TypeDataTable =      SearchDB.GetDataByRoomAvailability(DDRoomType.Text,     Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString())

Dim RoomDescription As String = GetAvailaibility(0)("Description")
Dim Price As Integer = GetAvailaibility(0)("Room_TariffID")
Dim Roomtypeid As Integer = GetAvailaibility(0)("Room_TypeID")
Dim DateCheckin As Date = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString

IDlabel.Text = Roomtypeid
roomlabel.Text = RoomDescription
pricelabel.Text = Price
Session("Room_TypeID") = Roomtypeid
Session("Description") = RoomDescription
Session("Check_in_date") = DateCheckin
Session("Room_TarriffID") = Price
```

Tried this if statement but still no luck

```
 If GetAvailability.Rows.Count > 0 Then Label1.text = ("Room unavailable")
```

Update:

If Statement works now I have put it in the correct place.

```
 If GetAvailability.Rows.Count > 0 then

Dim RoomDescription As String = GetAvailaibility(0)("Description")
Dim Price As Integer = GetAvailaibility(0)("Room_TariffID")
Dim Roomtypeid As Integer = GetAvailaibility(0)("Room_TypeID")
Dim DateCheckin As Date = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString

IDlabel.Text = Roomtypeid
roomlabel.Text = RoomDescription
pricelabel.Text = Price
Session("Room_TypeID") = Roomtypeid
Session("Description") = RoomDescription
Session("Check_in_date") = DateCheckin
Session("Room_TarriffID") = Price

Else Label1.text = ("Room Unavailable")
```

Comment: If you don't have any rows, you can't access the `(0)` index, it doesn't exist.  `If GetAvailability.Rows.Count > 0 Then`

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried exactly that but no luck!

Comment: You are going to have to update your post with what you tried.

Comment: You have to put the whole code block inside that `If Then` block.  Remember, if you don't have any rows, you can't use `GetAvailaibility(0)`.

Comment: is there something else i can use other than GetAvailability(0) ?

Comment: You could either wrap it in a Try Catch or use a short circuiting And along the lines of:

Comment: will give it a 'try' tomorrow thanks for response. Will keep you updated